# Webcomponents is re-initializing every time while working with Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, web-component, custom-element

I have created a webcomponent for a generic input boxes that i needed across multiple projects.
the design functionality remains same only i have to use switch themes on each projects.so i have decided to go on with webcomponents.One of the projects is based  on Vue Js.In Vue js the DOM content is re-rendered while each update for enabling reactivity. That re-rendering of vue template is reinitializing my custom webcomponent which will result in loosing all my configurations i have assigned to the component using setters.
I know the below solutions. but i wanted to use a setter method.

- pass data as Attributes
- Event based passing of configurations.
- Using Vue-directives.
- using v-show instead of v-if

  -- Above three solutions doesn't really match with what i am trying to create.

I have created a sample project in jsfiddle  to display my issue.
Each time i an unchecking and checking the checkbox new instances of my component is creating. which causes loosing the theme i have selected. (please check he active boxes count)
For this particular example i want blue theme to be displayed. but it keep changing to red

[JSFiddle direct Link](https://jsfiddle.net/harigopalmg/y635wfsq/68/)

```js
class InputBox extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        window.activeBoxes ? window.activeBoxes++ : window.activeBoxes = 1;
        var shadow = this.attachShadow({
            mode: 'open'
        });
        var template = `
         <style>
           .blue#iElem {
             background: #00f !important;
             color: #fff !important;
            }
      .green#iElem {
             background: #0f0 !important;
             color: #f00 !important;
            }
            #iElem {
                background: #f00;
                padding: 13px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                color: yellow;
                border: 0;
                outline: 0;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px -3px #000;
              
            }
          </style>
         <input id="iElem" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" type="text" />
        `;
        shadow.innerHTML = template;
        this._theme = 'red';
        
        this.changeTheme = function(){
         this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#iElem').className = '';
       this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#iElem').classList.add(this._theme);
        }
        
    }
    connectedCallback() {
     this.changeTheme();
    }
    set theme(val){
     this._theme = val;
      this.changeTheme();
  }
}
window.customElements.define('search-bar', InputBox);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Wrapper Component</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        font: 13px/18px sans-serif;
      }
      select {
        min-width: 300px;
      }
      search-bar {
        top: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 300px;
      }
      input {
        min-width: 20px;
        padding: 25px;
        top: 100px;
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="el"></div>

    <!-- using string template here to work around HTML <option> placement restriction -->
    <script type="text/x-template" id="demo-template">
      <div>
       
       <div class='parent' contentEditable='true' v-if='visible'>
          <search-bar ref='iBox'></search-bar>
        </div>
        <input type='checkbox' v-model='visible'>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-template" id="select2-template">
      <select>
        <slot></slot>
      </select>
    </script>

    <script>
      var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#el",
        template: "#demo-template",
        data: {
          visible: true,
        },
        mounted(){
          let self = this
            setTimeout(()=>{
              self.$refs.iBox.theme = 'blue';
            } , 0)
        }        
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class='parent' contentEditable='true' v-if='visible'>
     <search-bar ref='iBox'></search-bar>
</div>
<input type='checkbox' v-model='visible'>
```

Vue's `v-if` will add/remove the whole DIV from the DOM

So `<search-bar>` is also added/removed on every checkbox click

If you want a state for `<search-bar>` you have to save it someplace **outside** the `<search-bar>` component:

- JavaScript variable
- localStorage
- [.getRootnode().host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/getRootNode)
- [CSS Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) I would go with this one, as they trickle into shadowDOM
- ...
- ...

Or change your checkbox code to not use `v-if` but **hide** the `<div>` with any CSS:

- display: none
- visibility: hidden
- opacity: 0
- move to off screen location
- height: 0
- ...

and/or...

#### Managing multiple screen elements with Stylesheets

You can easily **toggle** styling using `<style>` elements:

```
<style id="SearchBox" onload="this.disabled=true">
 ... lots of CSS
 ... even more CSS
 ... and more CSS
</style>
```

The `onload` event makes sure the `<style>` is **not** applied on page load.

- activate **all** CSS styles:
  `(this.shadowRoot || document).getElementById("SearchBox").disabled = false`
- remove **all** CSS styles:
  `(this.shadowRoot || document).getElementById("SearchBox").disabled = true`

You do need [CSS Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for this to work in combo with shadowDOM Elements.

I prefer native over Frameworks. `<style v-if='visible'/>` will work.. by brutally removing/adding the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed informations @Danny .i have decided to go on with by attributes.